# how to decrease the height of content area for <p> with css?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, uiwebview

Could anyone tells me how to decrease the height of the content area for p tag with css?

I want to, 
1. bring the bottom orange dotted line closer to the text above. (border-bottom: 3px orange dotted;)
2. reduce the height of the yellow highlighting box. (body { background-color:yellow })

adjusting the properties "line-height" and "height" don't help...

Thanks!

[image: UIWebview]

Comment: please create a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change the height with the "line-height" property make sure there is not another css overwriting it. to make sure you can add !important at the end like this:

```
p {
  line-height: 1em !important; 
}
```

if that worked go back to your code and make sure you dont have another element changing the line-height

Comment: not reducing the height of content area, but causing text overlapping

Comment: could you show me the code? It will be a lot easier to explain.

use jfiddle.net

Comment: what if I use <span> instead of <p>? because the code doesn't work for <span>

Answer (score 1):

take the margin and padding off your p tag.

```
p {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

if that does not work for you put it in a div with a specified height;

```
<div class="myDiv">
<p>your p content</p>

</div>
```

style;

```
.myDiv {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 300px; //whatever height you want
width: 300px; //whatever width you want
}
```