# how to decrease the height of content area for <span> with css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, uiwebview

Could anyone tells me how to decrease the height of the content area for span tag with css?

I want to, 1. bring the bottom orange dotted line closer to the text above. (border-bottom: 3px orange dotted;) 2. reduce the height of the yellow highlighting box. (body { background-color:yellow })

I posted a similar question earlier about the p tag, but the rule doesn't apply to span tag. Guessing because the difference between a block and an inline.

[how to decrease the height of content area for <p> with css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526484/how-to-decrease-the-height-of-content-area-for-p-with-css)

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What is your HTML and CSS code that reproduce the problem? And is this really uiwebview-specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try set `display: inline-block`

```
span{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1em !important; 
}
```

value line-height from [how to decrease the height of content area for <p> with css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526484/how-to-decrease-the-height-of-content-area-for-p-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

```
<span style="line-height:70%"></span>
```